# How can I add a button that says menu when menu is small?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS responsive menu that I made. I would like to add a button that show menu when the screen is smaller. This is my link to [my current code pen](http://codepen.io/mlegg10/pen/oxmgdG)
here is the code in the stackoverflow code snippet

```css
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav li {
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
 
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}
 
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #036;
  color: #ffffff;
}
 
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
 
  /* Option 1 - Display Inline */
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }
 
  /* Options 2 - Float
  .nav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav ul {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: ffffff;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">Biography</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a [Hamburger Menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button)?

You'll need to use javascript for that. I don't think there's a way to hide and show a menu on button click with pure css. I could be wrong.

Comment: like these http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp  I saw this too but couldn't figure out how to add it into my menu https://codepen.io/derekmorash/pen/XddZJY

Comment: Ok. Well you could add a media query that hides and reveals the button. For example

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      button {
        display:block;
      }
    }

And then hide the button by default. For making the button hide and reveal the menu, you'll still need to use javascript. I hope that helps. Let me know if it does. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I've been using html for 17 yrs, since almost the beginning :P and obviously css for years too. I'm still learning javascript on my own. I usually use code snippets out there for the things I've needed to use it for.

Comment: I don't mean to offend. Maybe I just don't fully understand your question. I just know that if you want to show a menu through a button, you need javascript.

Comment: Also, it turns out I was wrong. Here is an article that might help you: [css checkboxes](http://clearleft.com/thinks/260)